# Why is 0 factorial 1?

Tags: factorial

n factorial is product of all numbers between n and 1.

0 factorial is (0 * 1 = 0).

Why is 0 factorial 1?

How can I proof this in mathematical way?

Comment: Factorial is about permutation without repetitions of $n$ objects.

Imagine you have $0$ objects.

How many possible permutations of those $0$ objects can you make? Just one.

$$0! = 1$$

Comment: I understood. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score -2):

It is just for definition of ! function
0=1! And n!=(n-1)!n

Comment: It's not just "by definition". 

Factorial is about permutation without repetitions of $n$ objects.

Imagine you have $0$ objects.

How many possible permutations of those $0$ objects can you make? Just one.

$$0! = 1$$

Comment: However, there just happens to be another reason why 0 factorial is equal to 1, aside from the fact that there is one possible permutation for zero. Suppose that we had n objects, for which we wished to permute into n number of places. From the permutation formula, we could deduce that the number of permutations for n objects into n places would equal n!/0!. On the other hand, we could interpret, from elementary deductive logic, that the result would eventually be 1/n. Thus, for n!/0! to be equivalent to 1/n, the only logical solution is to allow 0 factorial to be 1.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/prob-comb/combinatorics-precalc/v/zero-factorial-or-0